# Java - method reference for setter and getter

Tags: java, lambda, getter-setter, getter, setter

**A Pojo class:**

```
package com.lambda.jay;

public class Person {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Another class for initiating 'Person' objects:**

```
package com.fi.lambda.jay;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Actor {
    public <T,R> void printField(T obj, Function<? super T,? extends R> getter1) {
        System.out.println(getter1.apply(obj).toString());
    }

    public <T,R> void setField(T obj, R value, BiConsumer<T, R> setter) {
        setter.accept(obj, value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        Actor actor = new Actor();

        actor.setField(person, "Bob", Person::setName);// (a,b) -> a.setB(b);
        actor.printField(person, Person::getName);
    }
}
```

1. How do we interpret the java lambda used for setter?
   **BiConsumer<T, R>** functional interface has been used for parameter type for **setField** and **Person::setName** was passed as parameter value for the method.
   My understanding of **BiConsumer<T, R>** is that its a functional interface used to denote the lambda function with two input parameters and no return parameter i.e., (a,b) -> a+b;
   where *a+b* could be any logic(sequence of steps that uses  a and b parameters).
   But in the above code example BiConsumer<T, R> denotes the lambda function (personObject,nameValue) -> personObject.set(nameValue);
2. How do we interpret the java lambda used for getter?
   My understanding  **Function<T,R>** = (a) -> return math(a);
   Whereas in the above code example **Function<T,R>** = (personObject) -> return personObject.getName();

Can I get help to understand that above two interpretations please.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're hoping for.  You've clearly recognized what those lambdas are actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Exactly, a `BiConsumer` consumes 2 things. [A] An instance of the `Person` class, and [B] the value for the `name` field to set.
2. Yup. The input is an instance of `Person`, the output is the name of that person.

The key realization is that the `getter` lambda represents the getter itself **without** an actual person instance associated with it. If you do want that, you can; something like `somePersonInstance::getName` is a `Producer` (takes no inputs and provides an output), whereas something like `Person::getName` is a Function, takes 1 `Person` instance and provides an output.

Comment: Thank you for answering rzwitserloot . Can you help me with any reference of documentation about how java compiler interprets BiConsumer<T, R> as (personInstance,nameValue) -> personInstance.set(nameValue);

Comment: Sure. [Javadoc of `BiConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) and [basic tutorial on how lambdas work](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-lambda-expressions-tips).